# How to write a compound index when there are OR's in the WHERE clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to add a compound index to speed up the following query:

```
User.where("name = 'bob' AND (x IS TRUE OR y = 'foo' OR z = 'bar') AND image_url <> ''")
```

**How do I account for `x`, `y`, and `z`?**

I tried adding one index like so:

```
# rails migration file
add_index :users, [ :name, :x, :y, :z, :image_url ], name: "index_users_on_blah"
```

But it didn't appear to do anything...or at least I didn't notice any difference when I `EXPLAIN`d it.

Comment: Could you please post `explain analyze`?

Answer (score 1):

You might be better with partial index and columns should have different order:

```
create index index_users_on_blah on users (name, x, y, z) where image_url <> ''
```

Not sure if 'partial index' is supported by Rails but you should re-arrange index columns:

```
create index index_users_on_blah on users (name, image_url, x, y, z) where image_url <> ''
```

You should read this:

- [11.3. Multicolumn Indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/indexes-multicolumn.html)
- [11.5. Combining Multiple Indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/indexes-bitmap-scans.html)

Answer (score 0):

If that is the only set of conditions that you're interested in, could you try creating an index:

```
 create index index_name
 on table_name (
   name,
   case when x IS TRUE OR y = 'foo' OR z = 'bar'
        then true
        else false
   end)
```

... and rewrite your query to:

```
 name = 'Bob' and
 case when x IS TRUE OR y = 'foo' OR z = 'bar'
      then true
      else false
 end
```

I'm not sure how sensitive the PostgreSQL query optimiser is to whitespace, but give that a go first.

The drawback is that it's not very flexible if you wanted the same query but with x  being false.